# Reporting Services Report Manager Generating Report Message

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, reporting-services

We are using reporting services for our reports and are currently using the Report Manager application to allow users to run reports. The report manager application can be accessed from outside our firewall, so we have configured reporting services so that the report manager web application is on a separate server than the report server web service.

This configuration is working great, except when a user runs a report it does not show the 'Generating Report' message while the report is being generated. The screen does not change and shows no indication that it is working on generating the report. It does generate the report correctly, and everything works correctly, it just does not give the user any indication that the report is being generated.

I have only had this problem when we have the report manager and reportserver webservice on separate servers. I have done a lot of searching but have not found any information about what could be causing this or how I could possibly fix this issue. I would really appreciate any suggestions on how this can be fixed so that the user does get an indication that the report is being generated.

The 'generating report' message does display for a split second before the report is rendered. For example if a long report takes five minutes to run, I will get nothing for five minutes, then for a split second I will get the 'generating report' message and then it will show the report.

Thank You,

Eric

Answer (score 0):

Run it on the Report Server and do a view source when the "Generating Report" message is displayed.

Do the same on the other server when the "Generating Report" message should be displayed.

I suspect that some files/images might be missing.

Comment: I should have mentioned that is shows the 'generating report' message for a split second before the report is rendered.  So I think it has access to everything needed.  To be safe I did comare the source, and they where completely different.

Comment: So if the source files are different, then there is something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Have you run SQL Profiler on both machines to see what is going on when you run the report?  I have seen three server configurations where the ReportManager, the RS catalog db, and the SQL database were on separate machines and there was an enormous load on the RS catalog machine which brought everything to a standstill.

Hope this helps,

Bill